# Half margin when using text-align: center instead of text-align: left

Tags: html, css, margin, text-align, margin-left

I just figured out a strange behavior. I used a div with `text-align: center` and an inner div with `display: inline-block` to center the inner div. So nothing exciting so far. Then i added a left margin on the inner div, because I needed it to be shifted slightly to the right from the centered position. But the margin I added was always wrong and I just couldn't understand why. So I did some testing and figured out that when you use `text-align: center` you have to double the margin to get the right one, but why? I really would like to understand this behavior.

I made a quick fiddle, so you can see what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/wnjg5ks4/

Just in case you don't understand this part:

```
.container2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -175px;
}
```

The `margin-left: -175px` is there to "delete" the "natural" space between the left and centered version, so it's easier to compare just the margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child element, .center, is being centered correctly. The red box AND it's margin are being centered. Since it's the only element, you were able to double the margin to get the desired shift, but the image below should help. The orange highlight is the margin.

To just jog the element over a little, you could use `transform:translateX(100px);` or whatever value works for you.

[image]

Comment: Oh okay didn't thought about that. Very interesting. Is there a possibility to center the box independently from it's margin? Your idea using transform works fine, but I am still curious ;)

Comment: I don't really understand your question... :(